Spring LDAP AuthenticationException
We have three Active Directory domains in the different forests:
1) domain_1.dom (domain controller - dc.domain_1.dom:389) 
2) domain_2.gu (domain controller - dc.domain_2.gu:389) 
3) domain_3.rt (domain controller - dc.domain_3.rt:389) 

Between them there are two-way transitive trusts.
There is tech-account in domain_1.dom with read rights in all domains.
From Windows standard tools we can receive users from all domains by this tech-account:
$ADUser = 'tech@domain_1.dom' 
$pwd_secure_string = Read-Host "password" -AsSecureString 
$creds = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ADUser,$pwd_secure_string; 

$DC = 'dc.domain_2.gu:389' 

$SID = 'S-1-5-21-86078234-647216237-617849643-1473' 

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectClass=user)(objectSid=${SID}))" -Server $DC -Credential $creds 

DistinguishedName : CN=Snow Andy,OU=Arctic,OU=Company,DC=domain_2,DC=gu 
Enabled : True 
GivenName : Andy 
Name : Snow Andy 
ObjectClass : user 
ObjectGUID : f20133e9-c01f-4e21-ad7b-982caad6f364 
SamAccountName : asnow 
SID : S-1-5-21-86078234-647216237-617849643-1473 
Surname : Snow 
UserPrincipalName : asnow@domain_2.gu

But when we trying create LdapContextSource in application we have AuthenticationException.
Java code:
AdInfo adInfo = adSearchInfo.getAdInfo(); 
String url = adInfo.getUrl(); // ldap://dc.domain_2.gu:389 
AdSecrets secrets = adInfo.getSecrets(); 
String login = secrets.getLogin(); // tech@domain_1.dom 
String password = secrets.getPassword(); // password 

LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource(); contextSource.setUrl(url); 
contextSource.setUserDn(login); 
contextSource.setPassword(password); 
contextSource.afterPropertiesSet(); 

return new SingleContextSource(contextSource.getReadWriteContext()); 

For domain_1 this code runs successfully but for other domains contextSource.getReadWriteContext() throw this exception

org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09050F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09050F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563]
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:191) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:362) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:146) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadWriteContext(AbstractContextSource.java:181) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]

We tried use tech-account login as full distinguishedName: CN=tech,OU=TECH ACCOUNTS,OU=Access Groups,DC=domain_1,DC=dom but have same exception. Password is absolutely correct.
Tech-account is active and has read rights in all domains.

Pls test domain_1\tech as the connecting user (domain_1 = netbios domain name) . Or put " " at start and end of full DN of tech user above.
